# Longest Maximal Chain in a Poset

Tags: combinatorics, order-theory

I'm trying to study posets as part of a larger algorithm I'm creating. At the advice of a colleague, I'm reading *Enumerative Combinatorics* by Richard Stanley, but despite the length of the chapter, he doesn't seem to answer my fundamental question:

What is the name of the maximal chain that contains one element from every level (so all elements in $P_S$ are either in the chain or on the same level as an element on the chain)? Or to put it more technically:

> Given a finite poset P with underlying set $P_S$, define *Whatever this structure is called* $G$ as follows:
>
> $\forall e \in P_S: e \in G \vee \exists k \in G : k \not\le e$

I hope to identify this structure so I can better understand its properties and use it effectively in my work.

Comment: Your definition doesn’t imply that $G$ is a chain; in fact, $P_S$ always satisfies it.

Comment: How can I refine it so it implies a chain? What I'm trying to say is that its either on the longest maximal chain or it is on the level of one of those elements.

Comment: But *level* isn’t necessarily well-defined for an arbitrary partial order: consider [the smallest non-modular lattice](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/4/45/N_5_mit_Beschriftung.svg/200px-N_5_mit_Beschriftung.svg.png). Do you really just want a chain of maximal length? (There may be more than one chain of that maximal length.)

Comment: That's a good point. Is there a term for a poset where level is defined? Can I move forward by limiting my scope?

Comment: You probably want at least a [*graded poset*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graded_poset) and possibly the strictest notion of *ranked poset* given [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ranked_poset).

Comment: Forgive me, as this is not my area of expertise. Could I use the diamond isomorphism to map things like the nonmodular poset into one where my definition would hold?

Comment: It’s not mine, either, unfortunately. However, my understanding is that the diamond isomorphism theorem is a statement about the existence of certain isomorphisms between sublattices of a modular lattice, so I’d not expect it to be useful in the way that you suggest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could foliate the poset by using antichains, then you would have a concrete notion of a layer. You can then pick out elements layer by layer and form a chain. You can read more about this here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mirsky%27s_theorem

Comment: You use the word "foliate". Is the notion of dividing a poset into layers in any way relatable to the theory of foliations in differential geometry?

Comment: that is not a trivial connection to make. I'm not very familiar with the idea in mathematics but one place it finds application in physics is in the theory of causal set quantum gravity. There the foliation is for Lorentzian geometry, perhaps things are easier in the Riemannian case.